# How can i streaming and have the video available to download using Azure media services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I need to stream a tv signal (I have the rights) using azure media service. And at the same time i need to have as a video to be access and download it at least as a part But how can i access part of this continuous video. I thought that a job encoder was the tool but i can't find a way. Is any way to do it?

Comment: Are you using a pass through or encoding channel.  If using pas through you should be able to submit a standard encoding job with a clip setting.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Use **FFmpeg**  to  download any Azure media service video or live stream.
For this you need to have **FFmpeg** installed. No matter you are using Windows, Linux, or Mac OS.

Download latest FFmpeg here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

And you need to get the Azure Media Service smooth streaming URL of the video you are watching. Typically, this URL ends with **`'manifest'`**.

**Example :**

[image]

Refer this documents where you can find the step by step procedure to download or live stream

**1)**  https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/5/15/download-any-azure-media-service-video-or-live-stream-with-ffmpeg

**Solution  2:**  live event can be set to either a pass-through (an on-premises live encoder sends a multiple bitrate stream) or live encoding (an on-premises live encoder sends a single bitrate stream). For details about live streaming in Media Services v3, see Live events and live outputs.

**Live Event:**

When using the pass-through Live Event, you rely on your on-premises live encoder to generate a multiple bitrate video stream and send that as the contribution feed to the Live Event (using RTMP or fragmented-MP4 input protocol). The Live Event then carries through the incoming video streams to the dynamic packager (Streaming Endpoint) without any further transcoding.

**Live Encoding:**

When using cloud encoding with Media Services, you would configure your on-premises live encoder to send a single bitrate video as the contribution feed (up to 32Mbps aggregate) to the Live Event (using RTMP or fragmented-MP4 input protocol). The Live Event transcodes the incoming single bitrate stream into multiple bitrate video streams at varying resolutions to improve delivery and makes it available for delivery to playback devices via industry standard protocols like MPEG-DASH, Apple HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), and Microsoft Smooth Streaming.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-live-streaming-concept)